# How to solve integral with natural logarithm and product

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int{\frac{x}{4} \ln\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)}$$

Using [this integral table](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf), the more close case is (43). However, this is not the right one to use.

Do I have to integrate by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting $\frac{x}{4}=t$ we get $$x=4t$$ and $$dx=4dt$$ thus our integral will be $$-4\int t\ln(t)dt$$ we can be solved by parts, ok, the result should be
$$-4 \left(\frac{1}{2} t^2 \log (t)-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)+C$$ sorry for posting to late